# Laravel 8 syncWithPivotValues() do not work as expected

Tags: synchronization, pivot, laravel-8

I have three tables: audiences, companies and audience_company. Pivot table audience_company contains columns audience_id, company_id and type. So I differentiate data according type column. There is also unique index above all three columns in pivot table.

But as I use syncWithPivotValues() method to sync values in pivot table only the last type is inserted cause first types ar deleted. The code looks like this:

```
$audience->companies()->syncWithPivotValues([1, 2], ['type' => 'PURCHASE']);
$audience->companies()->syncWithPivotValues([1, 2], ['type' => 'ACTIVE']);
$audience->companies()->syncWithPivotValues([1, 2], ['type' => 'FAVORITE']);
```

At the end the last favorite type rewrites all previous types. Can somebody tell me please how to do it properly?

Comment: This is expected as you are syncing , and that means you have to describe the full situation at once. Everything thats not in there will be removed. 

Can you describe what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I did it using detach() and attach() methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I di it using detach() and attach() methods. Code look like:

```
protected function syncRelatedCompanies(Audience $audience, array $data)
{
    $audience->companies()->detach();  // Remove all from audience_company table
    $purchase_ids = $data['purchase_ids'] ?? [];
    $interaction_ids = $data['interaction_ids'] ?? [];
    $favorite_ids = $data['favorite_ids'] ?? [];

    $audience->companies()->attach($purchase_ids, ['type' => 'PURCHASE']);
    $audience->companies()->attach($interaction_ids, ['type' => 'INTERACTION']);
    $audience->companies()->attach($favorite_ids, ['type' => 'FAVORITE']);
}
```

Comment: Now I see what you were actually trying to do, I think what you needed was:
` $audience->companies()->sync([$purchase_ids => ['type' => 'PURCHASE'], $interaction_ids => ['type' => 'INTERACTION'], $favorite_ids => ['type' => 'FAVORITE']]);`

Comment: Nice, but I think my solution is more readable.